# Cannot Add/Edit Product in Wordpress Woocommerce - Page not loading

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, scripting, product, wp-admin

I am unable to add new products and edit current products.
Tried changing my theme, replaced the whole wp-admin folder with a new woocommerce folder but it didn't worked.
I thing there's some script which is not loading can someone please identify and help in resolution.

[image]